# Is there a way to keep the user signed in between native code and a WebView using Firebase Auth on Android?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-webview

I am interested in building native and WebView based Android screens. I would like to keep the user signed in when navigating from a native to WebView screen.
But I don't know how to achieve this.