# Firebase Auth in a Flutter app with WebView

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a Flutter app that uses Firebase Auth to handle authentication. However, some sections of the app use a [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) that shows content from the web version (which also uses Firebase Auth). My question is to how ensure that users that have signed in to the app are also signed in within the WebView.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing built into Firebase to automatically synchronize the authentication state from native code into a web view that is opened from this native code.

It should be possible to pass the ID token from the native code to the web view and use it there, but I've never tried that myself.

Some relevant links that I found:

- [How to pass Firebase Auth token to webView and register for notifications on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368242/how-to-pass-firebase-auth-token-to-webview-and-register-for-notifications-on-and) (describes the same problem, but then with Android - and unfortunately without an answer)
- [Is there a way to keep the user signed in between native code and a WebView using Firebase Auth on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320188/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-user-signed-in-between-native-code-and-a-webview-usin) (unfortunately also without an answer)
- [Webviews and social authentication with React Native](https://codeburst.io/webviews-and-social-authentication-with-react-native-cfecf96ac7d7) (blog post describing a workaround for this type of problem with Facebook login and react native)
- [How to do Authentication on native and pass to webView?](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/baz83s/how_to_do_authentication_on_native_and_pass_to/) (also with React Native, but [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/baz83s/how_to_do_authentication_on_native_and_pass_to/ekff7dd?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) looks promising)
- [capacitor-firebase-auth npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-firebase-auth) (plugin for Capacitor framework that propagates the token from native code to web view)

None of these are pre-built solutions for Flutter + WebView, but I hope that combined they allow you to build something yourself. If you do: please share it! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will look into your suggestions and post how I end up doing it.

Comment: @Alex -- how did you end up doing it?

Answer (score 0):

**High Level**

1. From Flutter mobile client, sign in to Firebase
2. Generate a unique Firestore document *for the logged in user*, setting whatever auth data you need to lookup via calls from the webView - eg, `uid`, `email`, etc
3. Pass that `doc.id` to the webView, and use that *token value* as a parameter for cloud functions being called from the webView, that require the logged-in user data

**Code**

Implementation requires 5 small JS blocks between Firebase cloud and the browser:

1. From Flutter mobile client, call cloud function to give you a unique token, where token will be a doc ID and data will have Auth User `uid`:

```
exports.getWebAppUserToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    let docRef = await firestore.collection('webTokens')
                                .add({uid : context.auth['uid']});

    return {'webToken' : docRef.id};
});
```

2. Pass the token into the url called to open the webview, eg: `http://app.com/appPage/<token>`, and then extract token in browser:

```
getValidationToken() {
  let href = window.location.href;
  let lastIdx = href.lastIndexOf('/');

  return href.substr(lastIdx + 1).trim();
}
```

3. Now from the browser you can call a cloud function using the token:

```
const authFuncCalledFromWeb = 
      firebase.functions().httpsCallable('authFuncCalledFromWeb');

const result = await authFuncCalledFromWeb(uiValidationToken);
```

4. Cloud function that uses the `webToken` to get `uid` for the request:

```
exports.authFuncCalledFromWeb = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let webToken = data; 
    let uid = await getWebTokenUid(webToken);

    // >>> do stuff that requires uid
});
```

5. Helper to lookup `webToken`:

```
getWebTokenUid = async function (webToken) {

    let webTokenDoc = await firestore.collection(appData.Collctn.webTokens)
                                     .doc(webToken).get();

    let webTokenDocData = webTokenDoc.data();

    return webTokenDocData['uid'];
}
```

=================

Here's a variation if you want to consider expiring the token:

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
let EXPIRES_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 20;

exports.getWebAppUserToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    logr.enter(`getWebAppUserToken`);

    const uid = appConfig.getLoggedInUid(context);
    logr.i(`uid: ${uid}`);

    // For Field.expires, consider that webToken will not be
    //      looked up until user clicks HTML submit action.
    //      So whatever interval we give, we should check in client
    //      On the other hand, user can only get this token through
    //      the app in a cloud func, so expires may not be nec.
    let expiresTimestamp = dateUtil.getNowNumericTimestamp() + EXPIRES_INTERVAL;

    let webTokenProfile = {
        [Field._created] : dateUtil.getNowReadableTimestampPST(),
        [Field.expires]  : expiresTimestamp,
        [Field.uid]      : uid,
    }

    let docRef = await firestore.collection('webTokens')
                                .add(webTokenProfile);

    let webToken = docRef.id;

    return {'data' : webToken};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for Firebase Auth with WebView in React Native:

```js
import React from 'react'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'

export default function HomeScreen(props) {
  // props.user represents firebase user
  const apiKey = props.user.toJSON().apiKey
  const authJS = `
        if (!("indexedDB" in window)) {
          alert("This browser doesn't support IndexedDB")
        } else {
          let indexdb = window.indexedDB.open('firebaseLocalStorageDb', 1)
          indexdb.onsuccess = function() {
            let db = indexdb.result
            let transaction = db.transaction('firebaseLocalStorage', 'readwrite')
            let storage = transaction.objectStore('firebaseLocalStorage')
            const request = storage.put({
              fbase_key: "firebase:authUser:${apiKey}:[DEFAULT]",
              value: ${JSON.stringify(props.user.toJSON())}
            });
          }
        }  
      `
  return <WebView
    injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={authJS}
    source={{
      uri: 'http://192.168.1.102:3000',
      baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.102:3000',
    }}
  />
}
```

Similar logic might be required in Flutter (JS injection).